# How to store status result in app and get it when app is restarted

Tags: android, paypal

how to restore payment status while application is started.i.e integrated paypal for app subscription,once app started it shows alert box for payment ,payment completed app going to same screen with out alertbox.if i exit from app and again started(restarted) then i want to get the payment stutus ,bcz i want to display the app screen based on status how to do it.here adding onActivity result

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {

                    status_result=true;
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                    // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                    // for more details.

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        }
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Preferences API http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get default preferences:

`SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Use this to save a value:

```
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("isPayed", "yes");
edit.apply();
```

and this to retrieve the value: `preferences.getString("isPayed", "No");`

Comment: It works with in application to store and retrieve the data,if we exit from app and started again then app not getting previously stored info..

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. This definitely works. Can you post the code where save and get are?

Answer (score 0):

You could try SharedPreferences. Whenever the payment activity is complete set the flag as 1.

Eg.

```
int flag = entry.getInt("flag",0);
if(flag==0)
{
// Payment alert
// Payment finished
// editor.putInt("flag", ++flag);
// editor.commit();
}
else 
{
//Don't display the dialog
}
```

In this way as the user finishes the payment set the flag as 1.